# What is the time complexity of an $O((\ln n)^{\ln n})$ algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computational-complexity

How can the time complexity of an $O((\ln n)^{\ln n})$ algorithm be simplified and compared to some other time complexities?

Comment: That's as simple as it gets... Maybe you want to rewrite it as $n^{\ln(\ln n)}$?

Comment: what do you want to compare it to?

Comment: @Alex I want to compare it to $O(n)$ or $O(\ln n)$

Comment: well that's easy pls see my answer

Answer (score 0):

some very simple calculation:  $\log n^{\log n} = v = e^{\log v} = n^{\log \log n}$ give some options depending on what you need.